# Applescript can't make <list> into type specifier -1700 error

Tags: applescript

Can anyone explain why the following piece of Applescript code returns an error:

```
tell application "Photos"
    set idList to {"v3xzjwPQT0y8a844gLHLHWg", "v3w3twPQT0y%%844gLgf4Wg"}
    set itemList to every media item in application "Photos" where its id is in idList
    log (count of itemList)
end tell
```

The error is:

```
error "Photos got an error: Can’t make {\"v3xzjwPQT0y8a844gLHLHWg\", \"v3w3twPQT0y%%844gLgf4Wg\"} into type specifier." number -1700 from {"v3xzjwPQT0y8a844gLHLHWg", "v3w3twPQT0y%%844gLgf4Wg"} to specifier
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Submit a bug report to Apple. By the way: In the third line delete `in application "Photos"` because there is a global application tell block. But even without this double reference the script throws an error

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in this line of code using OSX 10.9 and iPhoto.  Perhaps something changed in "Photos"/10.10?

In any event, do you still get the error if you move the line of code

```
set idList to {"v3xzjwPQT0y8a844gLHLHWg", "v3w3twPQT0y%%844gLgf4Wg"}
```

to just before the Tell "Photos" block?  The error is saying "Photos" got the error trying to make the idList.  So try defining the idList without Photos. I would think the list could be defined without telling Photos to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My goal is to get all images that are not in a certain album.
The error rises in the line

```
set itemList to every media item in application "Photos" where its id is in idList
```

Also this one-liner results in an error

```
set itemList to every media item in application "Photos" where its name is in {"bla"}
```

What works is the following line

```
set itemList to every media item in application "Photos" where its name is "bla"
```

But that does not solve the problem. Maybe someone has a suggestion how to do it.

Comment: It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can show your interest by [upvoting](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it or leaving a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

That feature does seem to be broken in Photos 4.  You can work around it in a couple of ways.  If your list is simple and fixed you can build up a command using `or` statements like so:

```
set itemList to every media item whose id is "wi9HoFU0SKCDianaQBtJBg" or id is "DT29HF1lRgCKOaIZFHoHrQ"
```

If you need something more flexible, you can use a repeat loop and build up the list through individual searches:

```
set idList to {"wi9HoFU0SKCDianaQBtJBg", "DT29HF1lRgCKOaIZFHoHrQ"}
tell application "Photos"
    set newList to {}
    repeat with thisID in idList
        set anItem to (first media item whose id is thisID)
        copy anItem to end of newList
    end repeat
end tell
```